# Dynamic knockout template with transition

Tags: javascript, templates, knockout.js

I'm working on a list which is rendered with a template binding. The items have a collapsed and expanded view which is decided by an observable property on the individual items. This is done by providing a function to the template name (just like in the knockout docs). So far so good, everything is well so far.
Now.. to the problem. I want to animate the transition when changing templates. So far I have manage to animate the "In-transition" (with the afterRender event) i.e when the new template is loaded. But I also want to make an "Out-transition" for the old template before it is removed.
This is how far I am now. 
http://jsbin.com/UvEraGO/15/edit?html,js,output

Any idea of how I can implement this "out-transition" ?

Here is the code:

```
[viewmodel.js]
var vm = {
  items: [{name: 'John', age:'34', expanded: ko.observable(false)},
          {name: 'David', age:'24', expanded: ko.observable(false)},
         {name: 'Graham', age:'14', expanded: ko.observable(false)},
         {name: 'Elly', age:'31', expanded: ko.observable(true)},
         {name: 'Sue', age:'53', expanded: ko.observable(false)},
          {name: 'Peter', age:'19', expanded: ko.observable(false)}]


};

vm.myTransition = function(el){
  $(el[1]).hide().slideDown(1000);
};

vm.templateSelector = function(item){
  return item.expanded() ? 'expanded_template' : 'collapsed_template';
}.bind(vm);

vm.toggleTemplate = function(item){
  item.expanded(!item.expanded());
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

And the html:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: templateSelector, foreach: items, afterRender: myTransition }"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="collapsed_template">
    <div style="min-height: 30px">
        <strong>Name: <span data-bind="text: name"></span></strong>
        <button data-bind="click: $parent.toggleTemplate">Expand</button>
        <div>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="expanded_template">
    <fieldset style="height: 100px; min-height: 8px">
        <legend>
            <strong>Name: <span data-bind="text: name"></span></strong>
        </legend>
        <div>
            Age: <span data-bind="text: age"></span>
            <button data-bind="click: $parent.toggleTemplate">collapse</button>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
</script>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the relevant code in the question as well (this makes sure the question is still relevant even if the link rots or jsbin changes things around).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A thought would be to create something like a `slideTemplate` binding and use that inside of your template.  It would look something like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.slideTemplate = {
    init: ko.bindingHandlers.template.init,
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, data, context) {
        //ensure that we have a dependency on the name
        var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()),
            name = options && typeof options === "object" ? ko.unwrap(options.name) : name,
            $el = $(element);

        if ($el.html()) {
            $el.slideUp(250, function() {
                ko.bindingHandlers.template.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, data, context);

                $el.slideDown(1000);
            });
        }
        else {
            ko.bindingHandlers.template.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, data, context);
        }
    }
};
```

Then, you would bind something like:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li  data-bind="slideTemplate: type">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/6J67k/

Comment: Thanks alot.. nice and simple solution.